Azure DevOps: Link Test case to User Story during bulk import
While conducting a bulk upload of test cases to Azure DevOps, I want each test case to be linked to an existing User Story with Link Type of Tested By.
Is this possible?

You can use the az boards work-item relation add command to link a test case to a work item.
Example (not tested):
az boards work-item relation add \
  --relation-type "Tested By" \
  --id $testCaseID \
  --target-id $workItemID \
  --organization $organization

Values for --relation-type can be found by running az boards work-item relation list-type (list work item relations supported in the organization).

According to this document on how to Import & update bulk work items with CSV files

You can add parent-child links between work items you import by indenting the title columns as shown in the example later in this article, Can I import a CSV file that have parent-child links?. However, you can't specify any other link types when importing or updating work items.

To add multiple Tested by links with muliple test cases to a certain user story, we can use this REST API request to add links.
Here is a sample PowerShell script for your reference.
$organization = "YourADOOrgName"
$project = "TheProjectName"
$MyPat = 'xxxxxx'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))

$headers = @{
  'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + "$B64Pat"
  'Content-Type' = 'application/json-patch+json'
}

$userStoryId = '2314'

$storyURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/wit/workitems/${userStoryId}?api-version=7.2-preview.3"

$testCaseIds = @(
  2315
  2319
)

$body = @()

foreach ($testCaseId in $testCaseIds) {
    $body += @{
        op = "add"
        path = "/relations/-"
        value = @{
            rel = "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Forward"
            url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wit/workItems/$testCaseId"
            attributes = @{
                isLocked = $false
                name = "Tested By"
            }
        }
    }
}

$jsonBody = ConvertTo-Json $body -Depth 10
$jsonBody 

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $storyURL -Headers $headers -Body $jsonBody


